# SJCL CBC Mode not decrypting

Tags: javascript, encryption, rncryptor, sjcl

Using RNCryptor which uses SJCL. I am trying to decrypt a hex message but when using CBC mode, things get weird. Apparently one must declare a beware statement when using CBC and I get an error.

```
function KeyForPassword(password, salt) {
    console.log("Creating key...");
    var hmacSHA256 = function (password) {
        var hasher = new sjcl.misc.hmac(password, sjcl.hash.sha256);
        this.encrypt = function () {
            return hasher.encrypt.apply(hasher, arguments);
        };
    };
    return sjcl.misc.pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 32 * 8, hmacSHA256);
};


function decrypt(password, message, options) {

    message = sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(message);

    options = options || {};

    var version = sjcl.bitArray.extract(message, 0 * 8, 8);
    var options = sjcl.bitArray.extract(message, 1 * 8, 8);

    var encryption_salt = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 2 * 8, 10 * 8);
    var encryption_key = _this.KeyForPassword(password, encryption_salt);

    var hmac_salt = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 10 * 8, 18 * 8);
    var hmac_key = _this.KeyForPassword(password, hmac_salt);

    var iv = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 18 * 8, 34 * 8);

    var ciphertext_end = sjcl.bitArray.bitLength(message) - (32 * 8);
    var ciphertext = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 34 * 8, ciphertext_end);

    var hmac = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, ciphertext_end);
    var expected_hmac = new sjcl.misc.hmac(hmac_key).encrypt(sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 0, ciphertext_end));

    // .equal is of consistent time
    if (! sjcl.bitArray.equal(hmac, expected_hmac)) {
      throw new sjcl.exception.corrupt("HMAC mismatch or bad password.");
    }

    var aes = new sjcl.cipher.aes(encryption_key);
    sjcl.beware["CBC mode is dangerous because it doesn't protect message integrity."]()
    var decrypted = sjcl.mode.cbc.decrypt(aes, ciphertext, iv);


    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```

Everything matches the encryption on the  Python side in terms of salts, keys, and the hashes. But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CBC mode is dangerous because it doesn't protect message integrity.' of undefined
```

I'm thought the method is deprecated so I then tried to use this CryptoJS method:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, encryption_key, {iv:iv});
```

This just returned a blank string.

I feel like I am really close, just need some help on this last part, thanks.

Comment: That's a bold move from the SJCL team to require the use of the `beware` function. Looking at the code, this should work. Are you sure you use a current version?

Comment: Got it from their [github](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/sjcl.js). Though on their current documentation, `beware` is no where to be found. Would much rather use Crypto-JS for the last step but the result is blank; can't seem to find any encoding for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Artjom B. stated, [cbc.js](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/cbc.js) is needed as well as [bitArray.js](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/bitArray.js) (necessary part of the decryption and something I was missing). The original code works fine now.

As an aside on the PBKDF2 iteration count as Rob Napier pointed out, it's slow. For this case (decryption), however, the 10K count worked quickly, but for encryption, I supplemented the kdf with CryptoJS's PBKDF2 at 1000 iterations instead (was getting bitArray error with sjcl's).

Answer (score 1):

#### SJCL

CBC is not included in the prebuilt sjcl.js if you look into [configure on GitHub](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/1.0.3/configure#L39). You have to include the CBC file (core/cbc.js) separately in your page or you would need to manipulate *configure* file to add cbc in that list of enabled modules.

#### CryptoJS

`decrypted` isn't a blank string. `CryptoJS.<cipher>.decrypt()` returns a `WordArray` object with a negative number of `sigBytes`. This property denotes the number of bytes that the `WordArray` is expected to contain. A negative number means that something went wrong. It doesn't always have to be a negative number.

There can be a number of problems:

- You don't have the correct key.
- You don't have the a properly sliced ciphertext.
- The `ciphertext` is not an OpenSSL formatted string or not a `CipherParams` object. Try to pass `{ciphertext: ciphertext}` instead.
- The key and IV are not correctly formatted: they should be `WordArray` objects.

Comment: Note that the key here is probably incorrect. The JavaScript version of RNCryptor uses 1000 PBKDF2 iterations. The Python version uses 10k. You need to change one or the other to make them match. (JavaScript computes PKBDF2 very slowly, so 10k can take a long time.)

Comment: I am logging all variables in hex encoding on both sides and everything matches up. Still can't use sjcl to decrypt after including the core/cbc.js file. PBKDF2 was using 10K on both sides. Yes it does take awhile when creating a key, but I only noticed when I was encrypting. Now that I'm decrypting, it doesn't take nearly as long for some reason.

Comment: No longer getting the `beware` exception thrown (using convenience.js `sjcl.decrypt` now). Problem now is that the decode function in `sjcl.json` is not being passed proper json. Converting to various encodings and strings has not been working either.